# JavaFX How to have the program continue doing something until a button is clicked

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

In my code I want to begin doing something when the user hits "start" and pause if the user hits "pause" and start up again once the user hits "play"

The pause button changes text to read play.

I'm having issues with stopping the program once it starts. The following is an extremely simplified version of my code, assuming all imports have been done:

```
boolean play = true;

Button pausebtn = new Button("Pause");
pausebtn.setOnAction( e -> {
       if(play == true)
       {
          pausebtn.setText("Play");
          play = false;
          //pause the printing that the "Start" button began
       }

       else
       {
          pausebtn.setText("Pause");
          play = true;
       }
});

Button startbtn = new Button("Start");
startbtn.setOnAction( e -> {
       //start printing from 1 to integer max
});
```

I know that the order of this code may need to be changed. But before I do that I want to just know exactly how I should go about doing this.

My actual code of course is much more complicated but this is basically what I want to happen: have the program start one execution when the start button is pressed, and pause it once the pause button is pressed, and start again once the play button is pressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem is. There seems to be nothing fundamentally wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Are you asking how to wait for `play` flag to become `true` ?